# .htaccess sub-folders to read parent folder file while maintaining 'pretty' url

Tags: .htaccess

This will have been asked and will have an answer. I cannot remember what this feature is and attempts to once again learn it have come up dry.

I'm looking to place a `.htaccess` file within a folder where the file to read is located, anything beyond that will read that file.

**Example:**

> - [www.url.com/articles/animals](http://www.url.com/articles/animals)
> - [www.url.com/articles/animals/safari](http://www.url.com/articles/animals/safari)
> - [www.url.com/articles/animals/safari/lions..](http://www.url.com/articles/animals/safari/lions..).

Would display the file at

> [www.url.com/articles/file-to-read.php](http://www.url.com/articles/file-to-read.php)

So you can then grab the `animals`, `safari`, `lions` to display the necessary content*, maintaining the 'pretty' URL.

**To clarify, I'm not asking for the code to obtain the path parts, this is just an example usage of said parts.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about the pattern matching and rewriting to the actual file on server, something like below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles/$1.php [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles/filetoread.php [L]
```

Comment: I have just gone though what you have suggested. Can you please confirm that the `. htaccess` file is to go within `site.com/articles/[here]`, the same location as the `index.php` file and then upon testing I should be able to go to ``site.com/articles/test`?

Comment: I've just tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]` which works for `articles/test` but the css breaks on `articles/test/test` even though it is correct for file location? I know I can set absolute URL's however I'd love to try and understand this more.

Comment: @TimMarshall hmm did you used the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` also, only when the request is not file present then it should rewrite.

Comment: It was a direct copy & paste, I only modified the folder `articles` to my actual folder. You have got me to the right place, so I'll mark this as the answer!